# How to set doctrine2 column time type mapping to oracle datetime type

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi i got this error when trying to retrieve data from oracle database using doctrine 2 ORM:

```
Could not convert database value "2000-01-01 00:00:00" to Doctrine Type time. 
Expected format: 1900-01-01 H:i:s 


The type of the requested column is  time. but oracle stores it in DateTime format and it 
set date to 2000-01-01. Doctrine retrieve the time using mask "1900-01-01".
```

When i insert a new Entity using Doctrine (Symfony), it passes, but when i insert a new recored in database table using Oracle SqlDeveloper, it won't work.

How to fix this problem ?

I use symfony Framework 2.4.3 + Doctrine

**EDIT**

This is the output exception:

```
2. at ConversionException ::conversionFailedFormat ('2000-01-01 02:00:00', 'time', '1900-01-01 H:i:s')
in /var/www/saga-print/shared/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/TimeType.php at line 67

3. at TimeType ->convertToPHPValue ('2000-01-01 02:00:00', object(OraclePlatform))
in /var/www/saga-print/shared/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/AbstractHydrator.php at line 330
```

**WHEN I change the year to 1900 it works.**

This is the attribute mapping

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="heure_livraison", type="time", nullable=true)
 *
 * @Assert\Time(message="Le champ 'Heure de livraison' n'est pas une heure valide.")
 */
protected $heureLivraison;
```

Comment: There is nothing like Oracle stores the value as you see it. It is just to display in the format we human understand. Can you show the query and please tell the expected result so that I can give you the query.

Comment: I added the output exception in EDIT section. Note that when i change the column value from '2000-01-01 02:00:00'  to '1900-01-01 02:00:00', it wotks !

Comment: Seems like Y2K bug reinvented. Can you execute the sql `SELECT TO_CHAR(date_column, 'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual` and show the output.

Comment: you're trying to map a datetime string to a time string (that's why they harcoded the date with the 1900-01-01) can you show us your entity? Seems like your mapping is wrong

Comment: I edited this question again. My mapping is well because i can persist and retrieve entities persisted using Doctrine. But When I use Oracle Sql developper to add new records in database, i got this error when i try to retrieve that record using Doctrine. So, i see that Oracle persist '2001-01-01 02:00:00' when i use Sql Developer, the same value contains  '1900-01-01 02:00:00' when is use doctrine. So problem comes from the mask used by Doctrine. It should be the same used by oracle sql developer.